# SSH Clone Gitlab connection to host HOSTNAME port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, clone

I am currently trying to clone a repo from Gitlabs to my google virtual machine.
I SSH into my VM and then try to clone Gitlab repo through SSH.
I receive the following error:

```
git clone git@domain:name/project.git
Cloning into 'project'...
ssh: connect to host domain port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I have copied my public ssh key to gitlabs.com/profile/keys. I am not sure if connection time out would be yielded upon not recognizing credentials. The credentials are correct, however.

My initial thought was that the vm used port 22 to clone and I also was using 22 to ssh into vm, so maybe that port is in use and not listening. I thought these results produced by running the following command on vm indicated that:

```
sudo lsof -i:22 ## see a specific port such as 22 ##
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd      482 root    3u  IPv4  13498      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd      482 root    4u  IPv6  13509      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd    15101 root    3u  IPv4  88752      0t0  TCP vm-csc362.c.databasesystems-287719.internal:ssh->externalip:20470 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    15119 ming    3u  IPv4  88752      0t0  TCP vm-csc362.c.databasesystems-287719.internal:ssh->externalip:20470 (ESTABLISHED)
```

This describes ESTABLISHED.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988424/lsof-connection-established#:~:text=lsof%20%2Di%20only%20shows%20you,or%20still%20attempting%20to%20authenticate.&text=The%20'ESTABLISHED'%20means%20the%20TCP,sees%20any%20data%20at%20all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988424/lsof-connection-established#:%7E:text=lsof%20%2Di%20only%20shows%20you,or%20still%20attempting%20to%20authenticate.&text=The%20%27ESTABLISHED%27%20means%20the%20TCP,sees%20any%20data%20at%20all).
`lsof -i` only shows you active tcp connections. So it doesn't tell you if there logged in or still attempting to authenticate. The `ESTABLISHED` means the TCP connection is established, ie the handshake has been performed on TCP/IP level. This is needed before the ssh process sees any data at all.

I ended up changing ports to 2222 (though it did not seem to detect this when running the above command on port 2222 and restarting service and updating firewall to allow that port), so I changed them back.
ssh is also listening on port 22 according to those results. I think my previous thought that a port was being blocked was wrong.

Would any happen to know what may be going on?

I read this post that talks about what could be going on: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229431/why-are-all-my-ssh-attempts-failing-due-to-timeout.
You are running an SSH server on that machine, and it does use the port on which you are trying to connect, but the machine has a firewall that does not allow you to connect to it. You'll need to figure out how to change the firewall, or maybe you need to ssh from a different host to be allowed in.

On the note of firewall, I had tried these to allow ports:

```
sudo ufw allow 2222/tcp
sudo ufw allow 22/tcp
```

I am pretty sure 22 is already allowed but I am no expert so I did it.

I have had no success.

Comment: What does `ssh -t git@domain` say?  You can also add up to 3 `-v`'s to get more information about what's happening at the SSH level (`ssh -t -vvv git@domain`).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to clone your repo by doesn't matter which way then it is possible to clone by `https` instead of `ssh`

Something like this:

```sh
$ git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:$GITLAB_TOKEN@domain/name/project.git
```

— where `GITLAB_TOKEN` is environment variable with your [personal access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) (with read permission to repo)